# Check whether processpool completed processing python3

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

How can i check whether process scheduled are completed in a process pool? i only have to execute rest of the code after finishing the process pool is there an way for this?

```
 executornan = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(20)      

    for l, ch in enumerate(chunks):
                print("CHUNK NUMBEr", l)
                print("CHUNKS", ch)
                futuresnan = [executornan.submit(locals()[configid + 5].ftptester, ch)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use shutdown:

```
for l, ch in enumerate(chunks):
            print("CHUNK NUMBEr", l)
            print("CHUNKS", ch)
            futuresnan = [executornan.submit(locals()[configid + 5].ftptester, ch)]
executornan.shutdown(wait=True)
```

This will wait until all tasks are completed and then it will shut down the pool.

NB: If you do not need to declare your pool outside your function, you can also use `with`:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(20) as executornan:
    for l, ch in enumerate(chunks):
         print("CHUNK NUMBEr", l)
         print("CHUNKS", ch)
         futuresnan = [executornan.submit(locals()[configid + 5].ftptester, ch)]
```

This will create a new pool when you hit this part of code, submit your tasks, then wait for all of them to be completed and then exit the `with` structure.

Comment: Can i give with in the for loop? Or out side forloop

Comment: It seems not working when i try to start new poolexecutor it gives me

Comment: Ah, sorry, of course outside the for loop. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: I would definitely go for the with structure, as shutdown will close the pool and you will need to initialise it again after the first use - so you do not benefit much from a global executornan variable.